# How does code blocks `{...}` with I/O redirection work?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

For example I have

sample.dat:

```
This is a 1st line.
This is a 2nd line.
```

when I type:

```
$ {read $line1; read $line2} < sample.dat
```

I got:

```
$ echo $line1
This is a 1st line.
$ echo $line2
This is a 2nd line.
```

So, I just thought that the above code may work in the same way as:

```
$ read $line1 < sample; read $line2 < sample.dat
```

but it turned out that it was not, the variables `$line1` and `$line2` are both "This is a 1st line.".

So, could anyone please explain me how code blocks with I/O redirection really work and how the statement `{read $line1; read $line2} < sample.dat` expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{..} < file` runs a set of commands on the input stream opened. The descriptor opened to read from the stream is not opened every-time but only just once, even if there are multiple commands to be run.

It is quite simple, once you understand the number of `read` calls you make at a given time. So basically doing `< sample.dat` redirects the content of the file to be made available in standard input or) file descriptor 0 (`STDIN_FILENO`)

With a single call to `read` you request *one* line to be read from this input stream which happens when you do

```
read line1 < sample.dat; read line2 < sample.dat
```

Since the `read` commands are separated (using `;`), each call opens the file once and reads *only* the first line available. The file descriptor opened by the first `read` command to read from standard input stream is closed once the first command is complete. The second call opens the standard input stream from the start offset again and does *not* advance to the second line.

But with

```
{ read line1 ; read line2 ; } < sample.dat
```

We open the file once and issue *two* calls to the `read` command. The first `read` gets the first line of input. Since the file descriptor is *not* closed yet, the second call to `read` advances the file pointer to seek to get the 2nd line of input from the file. Once both these commands complete, now the descriptor is closed.